# Excel VBA xml parsing - Loop through node which has specific attribute

Tags: excel, xml-parsing, vba

I have an XML file which is of below structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<BordereauxItem>
    <BordereauxMonth>Sep</BordereauxMonth>
    <BordereauxRef>2017-09-27</BordereauxRef>
    <EclipseBinderNumber>132</EclipseBinderNumber>
    <CertificateNumber>100</CertificateNumber>
</BordereauxItem>
<BordereauxItem>
    <BordereauxMonth>aUG</BordereauxMonth>
    <BordereauxRef>2017-09-27</BordereauxRef>
    <EclipseBinderNumber>142</EclipseBinderNumber>
    <CertificateNumber>200</CertificateNumber>
</BordereauxItem>
```

I just want to loop the node(BordereauxItem) for which the attribute(CertificateNumber = 200).

Currently I am able to loop all the nodes in the XML file, but not able to loop the particular node for which CertificateNumber = 200

As I am spending a couple of days in this without moving ahead, can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Hi @MichałTurczyn please find the code below

Comment: What code? I don't see any.

Comment: NodeValue = "//BordereauxItem/"
    Set list = oXMLFile.SelectNodes(NodeValue)

If (node.HasChildNodes) Then
        i = 4
            For Each childNode In node.ChildNodes
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(colval1 & i).Value = childNode.BaseName
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(colval2 & i).Value = childNode.Text
                i = i + 1
                val1 = childNode.BaseName
               
            Next childNode
End If

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple code to loop throguh nodes and check value of one of child nodes:

```
Sub LoopNodes()

Dim xml As String, node As String, childNode As String, searchStartIndex As Long, index As Long
searchStartIndex = 0

xml = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?><BordereauxItem><BordereauxMonth>Sep</BordereauxMonth><BordereauxRef>2017-09-27</BordereauxRef><EclipseBinderNumber>132</EclipseBinderNumber><CertificateNumber>100</CertificateNumber></BordereauxItem><BordereauxItem><BordereauxMonth>aUG</BordereauxMonth><BordereauxRef>2017-09-27</BordereauxRef><EclipseBinderNumber>142</EclipseBinderNumber><CertificateNumber>200</CertificateNumber></BordereauxItem>"
node = "BordereauxItem"
childNode = "CertificateNumber"

Do While True
    'find BordereauxItem node
    searchStartIndex = InStr(searchStartIndex + 1, xml, "<" + node + ">")
    If searchStartIndex = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No more nodes!"
        Exit Do
    End If

    'find CertificateNumber child node
    index = InStr(searchStartIndex, xml, "<" + childNode + ">") + 19
    'extract value and check it
    If Mid(xml, index, InStr(index, xml, "</" + childNode + ">") - index) = "200" Then
        'display node which meets requirements
        MsgBox Mid(xml, searchStartIndex, InStr(searchStartIndex + 1, xml, "</" + node + ">") + 17 - searchStartIndex)
    End If

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: First thank you so much for the response, i have 1 query in your code, can i able to retrieve all the childs of the particular Node after finding the Certificatenumber

Comment: @richardprabhakar I don't understand you. Code gets whole node with correct value, which is what you requested. For any further help, ask another question, don't ask questions in comments. Also, you shuold accept the answer if it solved your current problem (for further problems - ask another question).

Comment: Thank you @MichalTurczyn your code has solved my Query thank you so much once again, you are a Genius

Comment: @richardprabhakar Then, you should accept my answer (optionaly upvote).